# Alexa Skill/Lambda wont Log Request Body

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to Alexa Skill / Lambda. I am trying to print the body of my request. I have tried using fetch with isomorphic-unfetch and now I am trying to use the npm request module. For some reason I cannot get the request body to print in CloudWatch Logs, everything else I am log shows up fine. I am also not getting an error because I am logging that too and it is not showing up. What am I doing wrong? I am using account linking and I know that I have the user accessToken and I am using that token to verify who the user is by hitting another endpoint so I know I have the token and the method I have works if I run it locally and with just node but as soon as I try and log the body in on aws/lambda CloudWatch I cant get the body of the request to log so im not sure if its working. Now when I mean it works locally I mean I remove ${event.session.user.accessToken} and hardcode in the access token then run node index.js and then I can see the body of the request.

All help is welcome. Thanks!

```
 let skill;

  exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    getUserInfo(event);
    console.log(`REQUEST++++${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    if (!skill) {
      skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
        .addRequestHandlers(
          LaunchRequestHandler,
          CreateQuoteIntent,
          SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        )
        .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
        .create();
    }
    // console.log("SESSION**** " + event.session.user.accessToken);

    const response = await skill.invoke(event, context);
    console.log(`RESPONSE++++${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

    return response;
  };


function getUserInfo(event) {
    console.log("TOKEN: " +event.session.user.accessToken);
    const options = {  
        url: 'not showing url but api url is fine ',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Client-ID': 'not showing me key on stack',
          'Authorization': `OAuth ${event.session.user.accessToken}` 
        }
    };
    console.log('BEFORE REQUEST');
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        // let json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("BODY: " + body);
    });
    console.log('AFTER REQUEST');
}
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the requests package along with your lambda?